# can't connect to Access 2007 Database using Talend

Tags: ms-access, talend

I have a connetion problem while connecting to my Access Database. I selected the Database but when i checked the connection, an error message appear : error appear in 'Database configuration' page

when i clicked on details :   [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Ressources système insuffisantes.

Comment: Have you found what's the problem? I have the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Talendforge post: http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9389

You will need to install a driver.